# SQL CASE statement mutliple GUID's = same value

Tags: sql

I have a case statement that is as follows:

```
CASE id
  WHEN '9FDAC41CBF5ED6E3758' THEN 'Invalid' 
  WHEN '5EBF056B16E7593' THEN 'Invalid' 
  WHEN 'EEDC43399D10F44A19E293BB' THEN 'Invalid'
  WHEN '2322' THEN 'No'
  ELSE 'Yes'
END AS [Test]
```

Is it possible to put the 3 when clauses in 1 when clause since they are essentially returning the same value?

Comment: I personally think the way you have done it is best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. See below.

```
CASE WHEN [SomeColumn] = '9FDAC41CBF5ED6E3758' 
    OR [SomeColumn] = '5EBF056B16E7593' 
    OR [SomeColumn] = 'EEDC43399D10F44A19E293BB'
THEN 'Invalid'
WHEN '2322' THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'END AS [Test]
```

You could also use `IN`

```
CASE WHEN [SomeColumn] IN('9FDAC41CBF5ED6E3758', '5EBF056B16E7593', 'EEDC43399D10F44A19E293BB')
THEN 'Invalid'
WHEN '2322' THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'END AS [Test]
```

Comment: One can also use `[SomeColumn] IN (...)`

Comment: -1 doesn't do the same as OP's case statement. By rushing to get the first answer you've missed a condition

Comment: The OP was just edited. I'll update to reflect the changes. Also, please take a look at the edits before going -1 :)

Comment: Correct. That was my bad I frogot to include the third condition.

Comment: downvotes can be reversed after an edit, and gbn (unlike some) is very likely to reverse in light of a corrected answer.

Comment: Updated. If it was in the original, I missed it. Apologies.

Comment: And removed. I didn't downvote Chris Bint's also incorrect answer because there were no upvotes on that one

Comment: @gbn, I apologize for jumping you. I know the edit doesn't show it, but I could swear that the third condition wasn't in the OP.

Comment: no worries. Strictly speaking, the most elegant answer is JosephStyons one anyway :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
CASE 
    WHEN [SomeColumn] IN ('9FDAC41CBF5ED6E3758', '5EBF056B16E7593', 'EEDC43399D10F44A19E293BB') THEN 'Invalid'
    WHEN [SomeColumn] = '2322' THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END AS [Test]
```

Note: I've included your "no" condition too...

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to have a very long list of "invalid" guids, then you could store them in a separate table (INVALID_GUIDS in my example).  If you did that, your statement would look like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN [SomeColumn] IN (SELECT GUID FROM INVALID_GUIDS) THEN 'Invalid'
    WHEN [SomeColumn] = '2322' THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END AS [Test]
```

Comment: +1 I added a slight variation in case the `IN (SELECT GUID FROM INVALID_GUIDS)` isn't prefered

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN:
    WHEN id IN ('9FDAC41CBF5ED6E3758', '5EBF056B16E7593', 'EEDC43399D10F44A19E293BB') THEN 'Invalid' 
 ELSE 'Yes'
END AS [Test]
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose rather than a hard-coded list of GUIDs that these should rather be in a table somewhere, then you can use a SQL syntax as follows:

```
SELECT MyTable.ColumnA ...
WHERE MyTable.GUID NOT IN
(SELECT InvalidGUID FROM InvalidGUIDs)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight alternative to JosephStyons answer in case you don't prefer an inline query inside a case statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ig.Guid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN [SomeColumn] = '2322' THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS [Test]
FROM 
     YourTable yt
     LEFT JOIN INVALID_GUIDS ig
     ON yt.SomeColumn = ig.GUID
```